# "Stornry" Meaning

Tags: meaning

I was reading the Tao of Pooh, when I stumbled on this quote from the original Winnie the Pooh:

> "Can they fly?" asked Roo.
>
> "Yes," said Tigger, "they're very good flyers, Tiggers are, **Stornry** flyers."

What is the meaning of the word "Stornry?" I can guess from the context that it means very good, or excellent, but is it simply a word Tigger is making up on the spot here? I know Winnie the Pooh is known to use verbiage that is usually not considered within the age range of its target audience, is this another example of that?

Comment: There is no verbiage in Winnie the Pooh.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Based on [Galen Fott](http://blogfott.blogspot.com/2009/10/two-cheers-for-pooh.html)’s account, *stornry* is a typo found in American editions of [A. A. Milne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._A._Milne)'s 1928 *[The House at Pooh Corner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_House_at_Pooh_Corner)*; the English editions have *strornry* rather than *stornry* in the quoted passage.  Fott then remarks,

> it’s very obvious “strornry” is a British child’s way of saying “extraordinary” or “extraordinarily”.

Like *strornry*, both those words have three *r*’s in them, which I think makes it still more clear that *stornry* is a typo.  But note that a 1905 book by [Edith Nesbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._Nesbit), *[The Railway Children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Railway_Children)*, has a form with two *r*'s:

> “It is most extraordinary rum!” said Peter.
>   “Most stronery!” echoed Phyllis – *[The Railway Children](http://webapp1.dlib.indiana.edu/vwwp/view?docId=VAB7139;chunk.id=d1e8831;toc.depth=1;toc.id=d1e534;brand=vwwp;doc.view=0;query=)*, page 302 (Ch. XIV)

Comment: I had no idea...I guess you learn something new every day. Thanks!

Comment: So, it isn't a typo at all yet this answer gets all these votes? How can that be??

Comment: @Lambie, it is a typo... the original English edition has "st**R**ornery", but the American edition dropped that first R for no apparent reason, rendering the word's pseudo-phonetic spelling less effective.

Comment: I would not call it a typo, either way.

Comment: The earliest instance of _strornry_ that a Google Books search finds is from Herman Charles Merivale, [_Binko's Blues: A Tale for Children of All Growths_](https://books.google.com/books?id=8g8GAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA162&dq=%22strornry%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXm8vU9JXhAhUFiqwKHVsFAW8Q6AEIODAC#v=onepage&q=%22strornry%22&f=false) (1884), where it appears with a leading apostrophe: "Ozone be hanged. I mean—something to rouse in us—a 'strornry feelin—of xstrorny drowsinus—it's very odd : my eyes won't open keep—think—if you'll xcuse me —I'sh go—right—off sleep!"

Answer (score 13):

It's a children's contracted form of "Extraordinary", in much the same vein as how the author uses "heffalump" for "elephant" elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very example of how a child, mis-hearing something gets the wrong idea about how the expression is constructed. As a child I heard my mother say that I had a hernia that needed repair. For several years I thought that I had had "an ahernia."

You see the same thing commonly where people hear "should of" instead of "should have". When they are not quickly corrected, they show themselves up in adult life by using the incorrect grammar in public.

Comment: Yes, like undertoad for undertow, another famous example. This is actually the mechanism. Why aren't more people agreeing with this?? It just beats me.